# Detecting An Image is Bright or Dark?

Tags: image-processing, java

I use Java and I have some PNG images. I want to put a caption on my images. However I want that: if an image is bright I want to put a black text on image and if an image is dark I want to put a white text on it. How can I detect an image is bright or dark. This should be a fast algorithm and speed is a bit more important than accuracy.

Comment: If the image varies from light to dark across where your text goes, you'll have problems. Why not do all your text as light text with a dark outline, and then it stands out on *any* background. Not sure this is a stats question.

Comment: should this not be in stackoverflow? as glen_b already said invert the background. Or just use white text with dark edges. as this will always produce a result no matter the background.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about obtaining contrasting text, rather than statistics.

Comment: An example of the problem with choosing either a light or a dark text without a contrasting outline can be seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/vxTxWv6.png)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I don't think you need anything complex. As also stated in comments:
[image]